# Gulp RSync - Save progress to log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, rsync, logfile

I've been using [gulp-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync) for deploying static assets to my server via  gulp task.  And I use incremental option to determine whether a file needs to be updated or not. This works fine :)

I need save the progress displayed in the console in a file or whatever..
Because i need *purge individual files in the cache* on cloudflare :/

Looks like that (*in the console*):

```
[20:49:52] Starting 'rsync'...
[20:49:53] gulp-rsync: Starting rsync to my-ssh-hostname:/example/public-html/assets/...
[20:49:55] gulp-rsync: sending incremental file list
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync: favicon.ico
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync:         1150 100%  439.45kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=12/13)
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync: css/main.css
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync:         2712 100%  101.86kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=11/13)
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync: css/style.css
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync:         1445 100%   54.27kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=9/13)
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync: js/app.js
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync:        31878 100%    1.09MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#7, to-check=3/13)
[20:49:57] gulp-rsync: scripts.js
[20:50:01] gulp-rsync:        76988 100%    2.53MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#9, to-check=1/13)
[20:50:01] gulp-rsync: sent 2401 bytes  received 2820 bytes  10442.00 bytes/sec
[20:50:02] gulp-rsync: total size is 10106  speedup is 4.37
[20:50:02] gulp-rsync: Finished 'rsync' after 3.38 s
```

**I need save and extract the files in log:**

```
favicon.ico,
css/main.css,
css/style.css, 
js/app.js, 
scripts.js
```

-- My original "**gulpfile.js**" :

```
var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  gutil = require('gulp-util'),
  rsync = require('gulp-rsync'),
  logCapture = require('gulp-log-capture');

var config = {
  hostname : 'my-ssh-hostname',
  destination : '/example/public-html/assets/',
  progress: true,
  incremental: true,
  relative: true,
  emptyDirectories: true,
  recursive: true,
  clean: true,
  exclude: ['._', '.DS_Store' , 'thumbs.db', 'desktop.ini'],
  chmod: '775',
};

gulp.task('rsync', function (){
  return gulp.src('./my-local-dir/' + '**/*')
    .pipe(rsync(config))
});
```

-- I found the "**Log Capture Plugin for Gulp**" - [gulp-log-capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-log-capture)

What's the right way to use? :/

```
gulp.task('rsync', function (){
  return gulp.src('./my-local-dir/' + '**/*')
    .pipe(logCapture.start(process.stdout, 'write'))
    .pipe(rsync(config))
    .pipe(logCapture.stop('txt'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```

Any sugestions will be apreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `gulp-log-capture` for this because of the way that `gulp-rsync` works.

`gulp-rsync` waits until it has collected all the file names before it invokes `rsync`. Otherwise it would have to call `rsync` for each individual file which would severely degrade performance.

So by the time that `rsync` is invoked `logCapture` has already stopped capturing the log output.

You need to listen for the `'end'` event and capture the log output yourself by substituting `process.stdout.write()` with a function of your own (which is what `gulp-log-capture` does):

```
gulp.task('rsync', function (){
  var logOutput = "";
  var stdoutWrite;
  return gulp.src('./my-local-dir/' + '**/*')
    .on('end', function() {
      stdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;
      process.stdout.write = function(output) { logOutput += output; };
    })
    .pipe(rsync(config))
    .on('end', function() {
      process.stdout.write = stdoutWrite;
      process.stdout.write(logOutput);
      fs.writeFileSync('./dest/logOutput.txt', new Buffer(logOutput));
    });
});
```

This stores the progress log generated by `rsync` in the `logOutput` variable and writes it to the file `./dest/logOutput.txt`.

Extracting the files names from `logOutput` is now just a matter of coming up with the appropriate regexes. I'll leave that part to you. If this gives you trouble, it's probably best to ask the people over in [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, it helped to clear my mind! :)